# iterate trough map<List<dataModel>> in Dart Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 datamodels. the `userDataModel` and the `PostDataModel`.

Users may have multiple posts
so I would like to have the following fetching structure:

```
Map<userDataModel,List<PostDataModel>> = data
```

Can I iterate through data using indexes? (user index and then posts indexes ?)

something like `for(user, data in data){}`
or something like `data[0][0]`
In the end, I would like to have a listView of all the posts, one user at the time

I also would like to know how to print the data since printing data only returns instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using the structure you provided, `Map<userDataModel,List<PostDataModel>>`, you have to have two nested loops. To be able to iterate through all of them you will need to have some code like the following:

```dart
void main() {
  var data = Map<UserDataModel, List<PostDataModel>>();
  
 data.forEach((user, posts) {
   for (var post in posts) {
     print(post.name);
     print(user.id);
   }
 });
}

class UserDataModel {
  int id;
}

class PostDataModel {
  String name;
}
```

However, since, as you mentioned, your posts belong to users, I would put the `PostDataModel` inside the `UserDataModel`. Then, your data will eventually look a little different:

```dart
void main() {
  var data = List<UserDataModel>();
  
  data.add(UserDataModel(1, [PostDataModel("one"),PostDataModel("two")]));
  data.add(UserDataModel(2, [PostDataModel("three"),PostDataModel("four")]));
  
 for (var user in data) {
   for (var post in user.posts) {
      print(user);
      print(post);
   }
 }
}

class UserDataModel {
  int id;
  
  UserDataModel(this.id, this.posts);
  
  List<PostDataModel> posts;
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    var result = "";
    
    result += "Id: $id\n";
    
    var count = 0;
    for(var post in posts) {
      result += "Post $count, $post";
    }
    
    return result;
  }
}

class PostDataModel {
  String name;
  
  PostDataModel(this.name);
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return "Name: $name\n";
  }
}
```

It depends on your backend structure but I would suggest the second way.

As an answer to the second part of your question, look at the method `toString`. If you override it, you can customize the way your class is displayed when, for example, you use `print(userDataModel`. I created those classes as for example, so customize them for your own classes.

In fact, with the last example, you can access your posts by `data[0].posts[0]` as you requested.

Comment: I'm glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to iterate over the `Map` and over the `List` in a nested `forEach`:

```
data.forEach((user, posts) {
 print(user);
 posts.forEach((post) {
    print(post);
 });
 print('---'); // end of the user's posts
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like

`var data = userDataModel.map((user) => postDataModel.map((post) { post.useriD == user.userId ? post : null}).toList()).toList();`